# How to do something like cell reference in SQL?

Tags: sql, subquery, inner-join, where-clause

I'm doing the tutorial for sqlbolt and the answer key has this query:

```
SELECT city, longitude FROM north_american_cities
WHERE longitude < -87.629798
ORDER BY longitude ASC;
```

For list cities west of Chicago.

-87.629798 is Chicago's longitude but hard coding something here does not look good.

Is there a way to replace that with a variable that is the cell where the row name = "Chicago" in the longitude column?

In VBA that's called cell reference and Python pandas that term also kind of works, and also indexing but it's not working for me when I search with SQL.

Answer (score 2):

One option uses a subquery:

```
select city, longitude 
from north_american_cities c
where longitude < (select longitude from north_american_cities where city = 'Chicago')
order by longitude asc;
```

You can also self-`join`:

```
select c.city, c.longitude 
from north_american_cities c
inner join north_american_cities c1 on c.longitude < c1.longitude
where c1.city = 'Chicago'
order by c.longitude asc;
```

Comment: Oh, that makes so much sense since queries just return queries and this one just returns a single value. Thank you!

Is there any performance difference? The first one looks more readable to me for now at least.

Comment: @user2415706: note that this requires that there should not be more than one row in the table for Chicago. Otherwise, the subquery solution would error, and the join would duplicate the rows.